# Debian stretch ~ installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status ~ R.3.3.3

Tags: r, debian, tidyverse, stretch

I installed R program 3.3.3 in Debian stretch. However, I can not install tidyverse in R.

When I installed R 3.5 I had other problem: Rstudio was not starting. How to solve this problem? I've been doing this for several days, please help me.

My actual version

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

When I installed tidyverse

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
Installing package into ‘/home/init5/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘reprex’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/reprex_0.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1029128 bytes (1005 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 1005 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 61647 bytes (60 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 60 KB

* installing *source* package ‘reprex’ ...
** package ‘reprex’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/fs/libs/fs.so':
  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/fs/libs/fs.so: undefined symbol: R_ContinueUnwind
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘reprex’
* removing ‘/home/init5/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/reprex’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘reprex’ is not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/init5/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpUEkqMF/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In yaml::yaml.load_file(templateYaml) :
  bytecode version mismatch; using eval`
```

When I installed reprex is showed this

```
 > install.packages ("reprex")
Installing package into ‘/home/init5/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/reprex_0.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1029128 bytes (1005 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 1005 KB

* installing *source* package ‘reprex’ ...
** package ‘reprex’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/fs/libs/fs.so':
  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/fs/libs/fs.so: undefined symbol: R_ContinueUnwind
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘reprex’
* removing ‘/home/init5/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/reprex’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpUEkqMF/downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 0):

After different attempts during several days, my experience with this was: 
First. Within R

1. I followed the recommendations of other publications, with regard to installing some packages: `lubricate`,`Rcurl`, and `swirl` (with success). I attempted install `libcurl` unsuccessfully

> Warning message: package ‘libcurl’ is not available (for R version
>   3.3.3)

2. Then, I used `install.packages("tidyverse")` and I and showed the following

> Warning messages:
>     1: In install.packages("tidyverse") : installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status.
>   2: In install.packages("tidyverse") : installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

3. After, I attempted with `options(download.file.method = "wget")` and `install.packages(, method="curl")`

> Warning messages:
>   1: In install.packages(, method = "curl") :
>     installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status
>   2: In install.packages(, method = "curl") :
>     installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

4. Then, as root I used the following:

`gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9`

> gpg: key 4359ED62E084DAB9: public key "Totally Legit Signing Key " imported
>   gpg: key 51716619E084DAB9: public key "Michael Rutter " imported
>   gpg: Total number processed: 2
>   gpg:               imported: 2

```
root@debian:/home/init5#gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
```

> OK

```
root@debian:/home/init5# exit
```

> exit

Finally, I used the following codes unsuccessfully to install `tidyverse`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

5. After, I think these steps were fundamental. Run the following codes as root
   a. `sudo apt-get remove r-base-core`
   b. `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)/"`
   c. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9`
   d. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev`
   e. `sudo apt-get update`
   f. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
   g. `sudo apt-get install r-base`
   h. `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/R`
6. Then I went to Rstudio and used `install.packages("tidyverse")`.

> DONE (tidyverse)